# Built In Speakers do not work, headphones do, USB speakers do

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an HP All-in-one, (HP Pavilion All-in-One 24-xa0xxx), and everything has appeared to work on linux, except the built in speakers. The headphone jack works fine. I am running Arch Linux, but this isn't because of Arch, because it has not worked on Ubuntu. I have tried editing the file in  `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf` but that did almost nothing. On `pavucontrol`, it just says `Speakers (Unavailable)`. I have also tried editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, but to no avail also. Right now I have some USB speakers, they work fine, but they are a hassle because they take up an extra USB slot and have worse sound.Any help would be greatly appreciated. None of the tutorials or forum posts ever helped, and wildly ranged in answers.

```
% lspci             
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device a375 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
```

```
% pacmd list-sinks
2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.usb-CD002_CD002_CD002-01.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9049
    volume: front-left: 34182 /  52%,   front-right: 32897 /  50%
            balance -0.04
    base volume: 65536 / 100%
    volume steps: 256
    muted: no
    current latency: 1566.65 ms
    max request: 375 KiB
    max rewind: 375 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-CD002_CD002_CD002-01>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "CD002"
        alsa.long_card_name = "CD002 CD002 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-CD002_CD002_CD002-01"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "e2b7"
        device.vendor.name = "Jie Li"
        device.product.id = "0811"
        device.product.name = "CD002"
        device.serial = "CD002_CD002_CD002"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "384000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "192000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "CD002 Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    active port: <analog-output>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 62899 /  96% / -1.07 dB,   front-right: 62899 /  96% / -1.07 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 58.88 ms
    max request: 11 KiB
    max rewind: 11 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 60.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC225 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC225 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1398000 irq 129"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a348"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "384000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "192000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

Comment: Are you sure they don't have a hardware problem? Maybe you can check by booting another system, or a live distribution and see if it works. In my case, with an HP notebook, it didn't, so the problem was the internal speaker, not the system.

Comment: I never had any issues with it on windows, and I remember it still working on windows.

Comment: For me, it worked everywhere, until it didn't anymore. I mentioned it because it's a good idea to go over the checklist, it'd be a pity to waste time on a non-working piece of hardware.

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani I can confirm the speakers work on Windows. it can’t be a hardware issue.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I also turned off fast boot in windows. What else should i do

Comment: Something like this might work: check if you have a `/etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda.conf`, back it up if you do and then do `sudo echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" > /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda.conf` followed by a reboot. You are asking the `snd-hda-intel` driver to use its most generic version. If it doesn't work, remove the `/etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda.conf` and get the backup if there was one, to get back to the previous situation.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani thank you!!!!! I realized that that was the name of a file that was overwriting all of my configurations i was trying. Here's what I have that works: `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 model=generic probe_mask=1`, but the issue is, the speakers are always at zero, so i have to manually put them at the top in alsamixer. I am so grateful. (Fixed that too, it was on me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that that was the name of a file that was overwriting all of my configurations I was trying. Here's what I have that works: `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 model=generic probe_mask=1`.